# PHP upgrade grades

Tags: php

I have two arrays; `$marks` and `$grades`. `$marks` contain mark scored by a student and `$grades` is obtained by looping through `$marks` using the following function.

```
 function convertMarkToGrade($mark)
    {
        if($mark<21)
            return "D";
        else if($mark<33)
            return "C";
        else if($mark<41)
            return "B";
        else if($mark<=50)
            return "A";
    }
```

The problem is i want to upgrade the smallest and second smallest grades in `$grades` array using the following criteria

1. Upscaling is done from lowest grade to next higher grade and so on ie B to A, C to B etc
2. In case of tie in Grades the grade with highest mark is upgraded.

For example:
Let `$marks` be `array(25,43,36,16,28)`. So we get `$grades` as `array("C","A","B","D","C")`. i want to generate a `$upgraded_grades =array("C","A","B","C","B")` ie the D grade (the smallest grade) is upgraded and the C grade(second smallest grade but with maximum marks) is also upgraded.

How can I do it in php?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? From your question it's hard to determine exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you clarify yourself? I do'nt understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: BTW, you don't fail your students? :)

Comment: let $marks be array{25,43,36,16,28}. so we get $grades as array("C","A","B","D","C"). i want to generate a $upgraded_grades =array("C","A","B","C","B") ie the D grade (the smallest grade) is upgraded and the C grade(second smallest grade but with maximum marks) is also upgraded. hope you get it

Comment: Do you want to give the grades as per the highest score secured ? Suppose highest is 50 then 50 would be considered as 100% and grades for others would be calculated.

Comment: question updated with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Associative arrays. Here is a one of the method:

**Edited**:

```
//create associative array that has values as array of marks
$grades_arr = array("D" => array(), "C" => array(), "B" => array(), "A" => array() );

for($i = 0;$i < count($grades);$i++)
    array_push($grades_arr[$grades[$i]], $marks[$i]);

$loop = 0;
foreach($grades_arr as $key => &$value){
    if(empty($value))
        continue;

    if($loop == 2)
        break; //break after two upgrades
    else{
        $max = max($value);
        //unset the variable
        $value = array_diff($value, array($max));
        $value = array_values($value); 
        //push it into next higher grade
        array_push($grades_arr[chr(ord($key)-1)], $max);
        $loop++;
    }
}

print_r($grades_arr);
```

Comment: Wow. That works perfectly. But there is one small problem. When there is a tie, the grade with maximum marks should be upgraded. I think i can figure that out. Thanks :)

Comment: I dint find any easy solution. Do you have any clue?

Comment: That is awesome code. But small correction. It doesn't work if there is more than one D grade. Edited the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need this:

```
    $letterMark = ....; // "A","B","C" or "D"

    /* decrese number, that is increse letter by one
       but make sure it does not exceed 'A' mark 
    */
    $ordedMark = max(ord($letterMark)- 1, ord('A')); 
    $upscaledMark = chr($ordedMark);

    return $upscaledMark;
```

I wrapped this snippet into function here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/i9Rtgi

Comment: Sorry. This is not i wanted. Please refer the coments to the question.